# How to revoke refresh token on password reset?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am using [django-rest-framework-simplejwt](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) to get `access token` and `refresh token` .

The problem is that `refresh token` is not becoming invalid if I change the password of the user. Basically I can continue to send `refresh token` and get new access tokens even after user has changed password.

What I would like instead is to ask user to re-submit the username and new password to get a new pair of `access` and `refresh tokens`.

How would I accomplish this?

PS: Just because I am curious, shouldn't this be the default behaviour of the library? In what case would we want to retain the `refresh token` after credentials have changed?

Comment: I think you should use django signals

Comment: @JPG How?. Could you please explain

Comment: Now I have a second thought. What about revoking the token at the time of password resetting?

Comment: @JPG That's the issue. How do I 'revoke' a token?

Comment: Do you have a Passwordrest view or something?

Comment: @JPG Yes I do. How do I revoke inside it?

Comment: pls do add the view

Comment: @JPG Its just a normal view that send a form to user, gets back old password, new password. checks whether old password is same, then uses set_password to change the password. 
Does it matter though.... The problem is how to revoke the token.

Comment: @JPG Never Mind. I figured it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured how to get this working.
What I am did is put a signal that tracks if any required parameter has changed. If so, it blacklists all the refresh tokens associated with that user.
Here is the code:

> First add `'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist'` in installed apps. Then:

```
@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=User)
def revoke_tokens(sender, instance, update_fields, **kwargs):
    if not instance._state.adding: #instance._state.adding gives true if object is being created for the first time
        existing_user = User.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
        if instance.password != existing_user.password or instance.email != existing_user.email or instance.username != existing_user.username:
        # If any of these params have changed, blacklist the tokens
              outstanding_tokens = OutstandingToken.objects.filter(user__pk=instance.pk)
              # Not checking for expiry date as cron is supposed to flush the expired tokens
              # using manage.py flushexpiredtokens. But if You are not using cron, 
              # then you can add another filter that expiry_date__gt=datetime.datetime.now()

              for out_token in outstanding_tokens:
                   if hasattr(out_token, 'blacklistedtoken'):
                       # Token already blacklisted. Skip
                       continue

                       BlacklistedToken.objects.create(token=out_token)
```

WHat this code basically does is , gets all outstanding tokens for the user, then adds all of them to blacklist. You can get more info on outstanding/blacklisted tokens here. 
https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt#blacklist-app